# Chamar método dentro de um getter

Tags: java

É boa prática chamar um método qualquer dentro de um getter?

Exemplo:

```
public final class ScannerDeHtm {

    private static final String DIR_CEF = DefineDiretorio.getDiretorio() + "CEF";
    private static List<String> listaHtmFile;
    private static List<Jogo> listaJogos;

    private ScannerDeHtm() {}

    private static void scanHtmFile() throws IOException {

        List<String> listaSorteios;

        File arquivoHtm = new File(DIR_CEF + File.separator + "d_megasc.htm");

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(arquivoHtm.toPath());

            // ...
        }
    }

    public static List<Jogo> getListaJogos() {

        try {
            scanHtmFile();       // é boa prática?
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (listaJogos != null) {
            return new ArrayList<>(listaJogos);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

A outra forma seria inserir o método scanHtmFile() no construtor dessa classe, ou torná-lo público e chamar de forma estática quando for usar..
Mas continuo preferindo:

```
lista = ScannerDeHtm.getListaJogos();
```

a

```
ScannerDeHtm scan = new ScannerDeHtm(); 
lista = scan.getListaJogos();
```

E aí, o que acham?

Edit:
Vale salientar que essa Classe em questão só existe para retornar um List com os jogos e ela será muito utilizada nesse programa.

Comment: eu acho totalmente valido o que voce fez no metodo `getListaJogos()` ate por que se você quiser retornar algo diferente com base na lista de jogos, talvez um filtro, ou algo assim, você nao precisar rescrever o scan de HTML. Sem contar que eu acho mais organizado cada metodo fazendo um pedacinho do processo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Métodos `get` tem um único propósito: devolver valores. Eles não podem ser responsáveis por nenhum processamento mais complexo do que apenas devolver um valor. Como o `scanHtmFile` é um método que inicializa um atributo da classe, o ideal seria colocá-lo no construtor que possui esse papel de inicializador dos atributos. Assim, o get seria chamado apenas para devolver o valor inicializado. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public ScannerDeHtm() {
    try {
        listaJogos = scanHtmFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static List<Jogo> getListaJogos() {
    return listaJogos;
}
```

A respeito do atributo `listaJogos` ser estático ou não você precisa responder a seguinte pergunta: O atributo pertence à classe ou ao objeto?
Se o seu valor for igual para a classe, ele deverá ser estático, caso contrário ele não pode ser estático pois seu estado vai variar entre os objetos criados dessa classe.